# Can I do some pre-processing in AWS API Gateway before forwarding it to the actual backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am looking for a solution where the aws api gateway can add few extra headers before forwarding to the actual backend. I can imagine that keeping lambda function as a call back function can be one way to execute it. My calls can be slow, which means, if i use lambda functions in between, i pay a lot.

Is there any other way to do it ?

I am looking for something similar to a 'pre-processor' in Tibco Mashery. Which means, when the request comes, this method/logic is executed by api gateway, which will add the extra headers, and api gateway will forward the request to the actual backend.

Edit:
I need to fill the header dynamically based on the incoming request and some mapping tables in db.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably also check out the data transformation abilities of API Gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-data-transformations.html

Answer (score 3):

Add a CloudFront distribution in front of your API Gateway endpoint. Then add a Lambda@Edge function for origin requests that adds the extra headers.

See some example Lambda@Edge functions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html.

Comment: For this solution the API Gateway distribution should use the "Regional API endpoint" type, otherwise there'll be two CloudFront distributions in sequence in between: The API Gateway managed one and the custom one.

Comment: Will try this if it can work. This looks more like a 'lambda-in-between' model ?  (Updated my question.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

In the integration request you can add headers : [image]

You can store your new headers value in the stage variables : [image]

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for something more. Updated my question.. :)